# Php telegram bot: need to execute ssh shell

Tags: php, heroku, telegram-bot

I'm a really newbee to php and programming at all.
I have this code running on my telegram bot:

```
?php
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);
if(!$update)
{
  exit;
}
$message = isset($update['message']) ? $update['message'] : "";
$messageId = isset($message['message_id']) ? $message['message_id'] : "";
$chatId = isset($message['chat']['id']) ? $message['chat']['id'] : "";
$firstname = isset($message['chat']['first_name']) ? $message['chat']['first_name'] : "";
$lastname = isset($message['chat']['last_name']) ? $message['chat']['last_name'] : "";
$username = isset($message['chat']['username']) ? $message['chat']['username'] : "";
$date = isset($message['date']) ? $message['date'] : "";
$text = isset($message['text']) ? $message['text'] : "";
$text = trim($text);
$text = strtolower($text);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$response = '';
if(strpos($text, "/start") === 0 || $text=="ciao")
{   
    $response = "Ciao $firstname, questo bot ti permette di controllare Plex!";
}
elseif($text=="/accendi")
{
    $response = "Certo! attendi qualche minuto prima che sia operativo";
}
elseif($text=="/spegni")
{
    $response = "Certo! spengo il server";
}
else
{
    $response = "Comando non riconosciuto! non intasare la chat di puttanate!";
}
$parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId, "text" => $response);
$parameters["method"] = "sendMessage";
echo json_encode($parameters);
```

and I would like to execute this code when the message `/spegni` is received

```
    $connection = ssh2_connect('mydomain.org', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'secretpassowrd');

    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'shutdown -P now');
```

any ideas on how I could get it work?

Indeed I don't even know if this is possible :) I mean I managed to get it work on a previous version of the bot where I was using the `getupdate` method, but with the webhook one I can't get it work.

Comment: "can't get it working" is not nearly enough information to go on. You need to tell us what you expect to happen, what is actually happening, and include any relevant error messages in full.

Comment: Ok sorry. I got an old PC that i use as a NAS and i turn It on when i Need It and then turn It Off using ssh login through a Raspberry. The efford Is to have this bot to execute that ssh Shell when i send the /spegni msg in Telegram. When i add the ssh2 script to the main code under elseif($text=='/spegni') the whole bot won't work anymore.